# Ways of accessing MySQL from C#/WPF

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, linq

I'm new at WPF and C# and I'd like to know the best way of accessing MySQL.

Googling a little bit I've seen there's a Linq provider for MySQL. Is that the best way?
http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/

I've never used Linq before so I'll start today unless somebody knows a better way of doing that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the official [MySQL ADO.NET provider](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.0.html). Version 6.0 introduces basic support for Entity Framework

Answer (score 1):

It depends!  If I were coaching someone who was just starting out, I wouldn't start them out on LINQ.  You said you were just starting with C#, but maybe you have some depth in other environments, particularly with databases and maybe you are familiar with ORM.  IF that is true, then by all means dive head first into LINQ.  If not, then I'd suggest using ADO.NET for your database access in your first projects - it is simpler to start with and is somewhat foundational for other alternatives.

Comment: You're asking about my current experience. Well, I have worked before with MySQL and PHP. And I don't have experience with C# but I am more than experienced with AS3 (ECMAScript). Does it help?

Linq looks like a kind of XML's XPath right?

I am looking for information about ADO.Net and it looks like a more direct way of doing stuff right? I can just type the query, right?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate)?

/Broken record.

Comment: ...because NHibernate's LINQ support isn't expected to be finished until July?